# Not able to download image using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, php

I am trying download file http://images.anandtech.com/doci/5434/X79%20Extreme9Box_575px.jpg

but not able to download it using HttpUrlConnection, ImageIO.read and even in php using file_get_contents.

I am not able to figure it out why this is happening but if I check this link in browser then header response is 200 both in firefox as well as opera

Please help me

Now I notice that I am receiving 400 code.

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://images.anandtech.com/doci/5478/Screen Shot 2012-01-30 at 4.21.52 PM_575px.png
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)

Comment: those `<space>` in the URL are not properly encoded to `%20`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its working fine for me.

```
String path = "C:\\image.jpg";
URL url = new URL("http://images.anandtech.com/doci/5434/X79%20Extreme9Box_575px.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(path));
```

You can also try adding `User-Agent` string in your code.

```
URLConnection myconn = url.openConnection();

myconn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1");
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Java method you can use to download & save a resource using URLConnection:

```
public void saveStream( String mURL, String ofile ) throws Exception {
    InputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(mURL);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        in = urlConn.getInputStream();
        out = new FileOutputStream(ofile);
        int c;
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        while ((c = in.read(b)) != -1)
            out.write(b, 0, c);
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
saveStream("http://images.anandtech.com/doci/5434/X79%20Extreme9Box_575px.jpg",
           "/home/john/saved.gif");
```

Comment: Nice edit.  +1  Deleted some noise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Server allows only specific user agents to access the image. Try to set your user agent via `connection.setRequestProperty ("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0");`.